# Java two Set objects - hashCode() are the same but .equals() fails

Tags: java, hash, set, linkedhashset

I have two sets (LinkedHashSet) of a custom objects which overrides the hashCode() and equals() methods.

When comparing these two sets the equal() method fails even though the hash codes are the same.

```
    System.out.println("cmContacts.equals(cm2Contacts):" + cmContacts.equals(cm2Contacts));
    System.out.println("cm2Contacts.equals(cmContacts):" + cm2Contacts.equals(cmContacts));
    System.out.println("compare hash codes:" + ( cm2Contacts.hashCode() == cmContacts.hashCode() ) );
```

This returns:

cmContacts.equals(cm2Contacts):false

cm2Contacts.equals(cmContacts):false

compare hash codes:true

According to the documentation if the hash codes are the same the equals method should return true.

> The hash code of a set is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of the elements in the set, where the hash code of a null element is defined to be zero. This ensures that s1.equals(s2) implies that s1.hashCode()==s2.hashCode() for any two sets s1 and s2, as required by the general contract of Object.hashCode().

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: equals() does not *depend*
 on hashCode().  It's up to the implementer to ensure consistent behaviour.  AKA there's something wrong with your custom objects.

Comment: `a implies b` does not mean `b implies a`.

Comment: Due to hash collisions, unequal objects may very well have the same hash code.

Comment: The documentation you quoted says exactly the opposite of what you have claimed.

Comment: I get it now, there was a mistake in the overridden equals method. Will accept an answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got it backwards: if two objects are equal, they must have the same hash code. Having the same hash code does not imply that the objects should be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Same `hashcode()` does not mean `equals`.

You can compare that to ZipCode. You and your neighbhour have the same but are not the same.